# Implement variable binding in mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

**Description**

---

I'm trying to wrap the `MatDatePicker` in a custom component called `MyDatePicker` so that I can use it in the html as the following.

**Issue**

---

The `dateVariable` is always undefined and seems the two-way binding I implemented below is not working. Once the user selects a new date from the picker, the setter gets called. However, the new value is not binded to the `dateVariable`.

**Questions**

---

- How can I implement a two-way binding between my custom date picker and a variable?
- How is it possible to implement a one-way binding (from date picker -> variable)?

**Implementation**

---

HTML file:

```
<my-datepicker [(selectedDate)]="dateVariable" placeholder="some text"></my-datepicker>

<button (click)="btnClick()">Show Selected Date</button>
```

The TS file:

```
//...

    dateVariable: string;       

    btnClick() {

      console.log('selected date:', this.dateVariable);
   }
//...
```

MyDatepicker.component.ts

```
export class MyDatepickerComponent {

    dateValue: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string;

    @Output() dateChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @Input()
    get selectedDate() {
        console.log('getter');
        return this.dateValue;
    }
    set selectedDate(val) {
        console.log('setter');
        this.dateValue = val;
        this.dateChange.emit(this.dateValue);
    }

    pickerEvent(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
        this.selectedDate = event.value.toISOString();
    }
}
```

MyDatepicker.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]='pickerDate' placeholder='{{placeholder}}' (dateInput)="pickerEvent($event)">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]='pickerDate'></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated: For the two-way binding `[()]` (banana-in-a-box syntax)
we have to write an `@Input` with the corresponding `@Output` like:

```
@Input() selectedDate: Date;

@Output() selectedDateChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();
```

This can be used with an Input-Binding and a separate Output-Binding:

```
<my-datepicker [selectedDate]="dateVariable" (selectedDateChange)="dateVariable = $event" placeholder="some text"></my-datepicker>
```

Or with a little syntactic sugar provided by Angular with the banana-in-the-box syntax:

```
<my-datepicker [(selectedDate)]="dateVariable" placeholder="some text"></my-datepicker>
```

Aside Notes:

1) I think you need to bind the `matInput` with the actual `Date` value as well

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]='pickerDate' [value]="selectedDate" placeholder='{{placeholder}}' (dateInput)="pickerEvent($event)">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]='pickerDate'></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

2) If you want to use `my-datepicker` inside of an Angular form you need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface

3) If the only reason you are writing this custom component is that you want to use an ISO date string as input I would suggest handling this transformation on an API / Service level instead of in a component.

Comment: Why do you think I need to "bind the matInput with the actual Date value as well"? I changed the name as you said and it works. Without binding the matInpur with the Date

Comment: Also when I do that ([value]="selectedDate") it runs the getter multiple times !

Comment: I was not sure if you need it. If it works for you that way everything is fine :)
The multiple setter calls are most likely due to the change-detection in Angular, which is triggered behind the scenes on several events that occur in the browser by default.
You can change that if you change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of your datepicker component to `OnPush` but then you will have to work with immutable datastructures

Answer (score 1):

For two-way-binding to work, the `Output()` has to be named the same as the `Input()` with the suffix `Change`. So change your code as such:

```ts
@Output() selectedDateChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and the same in the setter:

```ts
set selectedDate(val) {
    console.log('setter');
    this.dateValue = val;
    this.selectedDateChange.emit(this.dateValue);
}
```